# Error starting custom service using nsis script

Tags: windows, windows-services, nsis, installutil

I'm receiving the error "14001- wrong configuration of Side by Side" when I use InstallUtil via my NSIS script. 
When I use the same command manually, the service install and start just fine, but when I put on NSIS it broke and show this error. 
I'd tried to create a bat file and run but it works as well.
My flow is:
My script creates a folder into `C:\Program Files\My Folder`, add all files compressed into `setup.exe` and try to install a service using: 
"InstallUtil.exe" -i "$INSTDIR\GeneteLPRService.exe" 
As I said, service install but isn't starting. 
the Event log of windows is ID 59:
Failure generating context of ativation to "...\exe.Manifest". Error on manifest file or policy "...exe.Config". 
But as I'd said, manually this doens't happened.

Comment: Which exe fails? InstallLib or the service in the event log?

Comment: Service in the event log... My service calls "LprService". When I tried to start it fails

Comment: Your service starts another application? And this other application is the process that fails with the SxS error?

Answer (score 0):

Find that.

Looks like this is an generic error, in my case is because some config file broken!